# Most efficient way to fill circles in python

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, hough-transform

I found circles (its radius and center) using hough transform in python-opencv. I need to make a mask by filling in the circles with maximum intensity. But this filling part is very slow using the inbuilt method `cv2.circle(hough_img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],255,-1)`.
I want to make this filling faster. Is there any efficient method to do it in less time?

Comment: I'd assume that finding the circles with Hough is much slower than drawing them.

Comment: _Faster_ have you profiled it? How long does it take now? What's your time limit? Please show some more code... See how to do a [mcve]